# Critical tunnel failure error blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have developed a app for blackberry ,its approved from appworld but it gives following error

```
on 4.6

Critical tunnel failure
```

and

```
on 5.0 and 6.0
ava.io APN not specified
```

please help why this error is coming and how to solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Problem is you didn't add appropriate connection suffix to the url.

Follow the link can solve your problem:http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_make_an_HTTP_or_socket_connection.html?nodeid=826935&vernum=0

And also ou can use the following sample code:

```
private static String getConnectionString(){
    String connectionString="";
    if(WLANInfo.getWLANState()==WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED){
        connectionString=";interface=wifi";
    }

     else if((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS){
         connectionString = ";deviceside=false";
    }
        else if((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT)==CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT){
            String carrierUid=getCarrierBIBSUid();
            if(carrierUid == null) {
                connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
            }
            else{
                 connectionString = ";deviceside=false;connectionUID="+carrierUid + ";ConnectionType=mds-public";
                }               
            }
     else if(CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_NONE)
        {

        }
    return connectionString;
    }
```

Comment: The link attached by You not working now. Could you please describe how can I use `getConnectionString()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear up some issues.

@Jisson your answer was helpful

But you did not include code for the method getCarrierBIBSUid()

```
/**
 * Looks through the phone's service book for a carrier provided BIBS network
 * @return The uid used to connect to that network.
 */
private static String getCarrierBIBSUid()
{

    ServiceRecord[] records = ServiceBook.getSB().getRecords();
    int currentRecord;

    for(currentRecord = 0; currentRecord < records.length; currentRecord++)
    {
        if(records[currentRecord].getCid().toLowerCase().equals("ippp"))
        {
            if(records[currentRecord].getName().toLowerCase().indexOf("bibs") >= 0)
            {
                return records[currentRecord].getUid();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Also it might be helpful to include

```
    if (DeviceInfo.isSimulator()){
        return   ";deviceSide=true";    
    }
```

At the beginning of the getConnectionString() method
For more info see [Melick's Blog](http://melick-rajee.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-connect-to-internet-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by setting the **APN** values on the phone its self and using the connection string code suggested in the other answers.

Change your APN settings (in South Africa)

```
On Home screen, click Options
Click Advanced Options and then TCP
Enter the APN: **internet** 
   username: **guest**
   password: **guest**
Press the Menu key and select Save
```

(for rest of the world find your settings here)
From http://www.blackberrytune.com/blackberry-tcp-ip-apn-settings/
and 
http://www.blackberryfaq.com/index.php/Carrier_specific_APN/TCP_settings